# HH404 Hardhat error at correct entry-point to an existance fi

Tags: hardhat

I have that route and It fails to compile but if I change `@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Burnable.sol` to `@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol` it compiles without problems.
How it can happen and how I can fix it? I'm desperate and I can think about a solution...
[image: paths]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the next learning in process person here:
Solution:
"./@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Burnable.sol";